# What's best CNAME or A record for www.?

Tags: dns, amazon-route53

On my DNS (Amazon Route 53) I have an A name:

**mydomain.com -> IP Address**

For www.mydomain.com do I use another A record **www.mydomain.com -> IP Address** or shall I use a CNAME that redirects **www.mydomain.com -> mydomain.com**?

Using the "dig www.arandomwebsite.com" command in Terminal I've looked at CNAME and A records of other live sites and noticed companies do it either way.

Note my site is low traffic.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 different questions to answer here:

Q1) Is the same web server answering requests for both websites?

If yes, the CNAME is *slightly* easier to maintain, since there's less to update when something changes. I.e. someday you may want multiple A records for your webserver, why maintain two lists?

Q2) Do you want *both* websites to serve content?

Be careful with this answer, you probably want to say "NO".

If they both serve all your content, Google will penalize you! Google sees "two" web sites with the same content. Each may get half the traffic, links, etc. Visitors will be confused when searching, bookmarking, etc. The simple way to fix it is to have one website do an HTTP 301 permanent redirect to the other one. (This cannot be done at the DNS level. The easy way is to do it at the virtual hosts level.)

If you say "yes" to question #2, you will at least want *all* your HTML to have a [canonical URL](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/seo-advice-url-canonicalization/).